# Python code repeating n+1 times every run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on an application which contains a small, simple http server to handle post requests on occasion. The server and all functionality around it works fine, but each time the server runs, log output would tell me that my code is being run multiple times, plus one time for each request the http server handles.

```
class HttpApp:
    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=25565):
        logging = Util.configure_logging(__name__)
        server_address = (host, port)
        httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, ServerObject)
        logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
        try:
            httpd.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        httpd.server_close()
        logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')

class ServerObject(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        print("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(self.path), str(self.headers))
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        content_type = str(self.headers['Content-Type'])
        # print(content_length)
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        if content_type == "application/json":
            parsed_data = json.loads(post_data.decode('utf-8'))
        else:
            print("Bad request!")
            self._set_response()
            self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"Response": "Bad Request"}).encode('utf-8'))
        print("POST request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n" %
            (str(self.path), str(self.headers), parsed_data))
        print("Parsed Params: %s" % parsed_data)
        def free_port():
            free_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            free_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 0))
            free_socket.listen(5)
            port = free_socket.getsockname()[1]
            free_socket.close()
            return port
        rand_port = free_port()
        SpawnSlave(category=parsed_data["category"], tag=parsed_data["tag"], filename=parsed_data["filename"], port=rand_port)
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({"port": rand_port}).encode('utf-8'))
```

A cli application passes information to HttpApp, which then starts based on that information. Once it receives a connection the first time, it goes through its steps normally and only prints output once. The second time, output is printed twice, and so on. Only post requests are handled by this server. I have gone over my code a few times to make sure I'm not calling it more than once, but I seem to be stumped. For more context, more of this code is available on [github](https://github.com/gageleblanc/upldr/tree/update-upldr), but this is the only relevant piece.

Comment: how do you run it? If you use threads/processes then it may run it many times.

Comment: we can't run it so you will have to debug it on your own. Put more `log` or `print()` to see when it create new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this wasn't an issue with my code, but rather an issue with the logger I was using which was adding multiple console handlers for the same logger, causing output to be repeated. I fixed this in my cli library.